# Error validating two inputText fields together

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I have a form with **two input fields** that have to be **validated together**. I used this [BalusC tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html) as starting point.

The **requirement** is a logical XOR: **one of the fields must be filled but not both together**.

This works fine for all cases except this one:

1) Fill the first field and let the second blank

2) Move to the next page (values get saved)

3) Go back to the first page, **delete first field and fill second field**.

Then I get the error message from my validator ("Do not fill both fields") although I deleted the first.

Here is the code:

```
<h:inputText id="bbvol" size="10" value="#{a6.behandlungsvolumen.wert}"
         required="#{empty param['Laborwerte:pvol']}">
     <f:convertNumber locale="de"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="pvol" size="10" value="#{a6.plasmavolumen.wert}"
         required="#{empty param['Laborwerte:bbvol']}">
     <f:convertNumber locale="de"/>
     <f:validator validatorId="volumeValidator" for="pvol"/>
     <f:attribute name="bbv_value" value="Laborwerte:bbvol" />
</h:inputText>
```

VolumeValidator:

```
public class VolumeValidator implements Validator {

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        // Obtain the client ID of the first volume field from f:attribute.
        String bbvolID = (String) component.getAttributes().get("bbv_value");
        // Find the actual JSF component for the client ID.
        UIInput bbvolInput = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent(bbvolID);
        // Get its value, the entered value of the first field.
        Number bbvol = (Number) bbvolInput.getValue();
        // Get the value of the second field
        Number pvol = (Number) value;
        // Check if only one of the fields is set
        if (bbvol != null && pvol != null) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Do not fill both fields!", null));
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging this case reveals that the line

```
Number bbvol = (Number) bbvolInput.getValue();
```

still holds the old value and not the new.

I tried to use `getSubmittedValue()` instead of `getValue()` and **this works**. But javadoc for this method says:

> This method should only be used by the
>   decode() and validate() method of this
>   component, or its corresponding
>   Renderer.

I am not sure if I can use this method without running in problems later.

So my questions are:

What is the reason for this issue?

Is using `getSubmittedValue()` instead of `getValue()` a real solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not solve the problem. If you test `getSubmittedValue()`, then the validation will (incorrectly) pass when you fill both fields. In JSF, input components are validated in the order as they appear in the component tree. When a component is successfully been converted/validated, then the submitted value is set to `null` and the value is set with the converted/validated submitted value.

However, your particular case strikes me. I can replicate this problem with Mojarra 2.0.4 on Tomcat 7.0.11. The `getValue()` returns the model value instead of the component value. I'm not sure if that's a bug or new in JSF2 or something, I am however confident that it has worked that way in JSF 1.x. I believe this is related to changes with regard to the new JSF2 state management. I have to verify the one and other first (and probably also rewrite the multiple field validation blog article).

As another solution you could add a `<h:inputHidden>` **before** the two components as follows so that you can utilize `getSubmittedValue()` the right way:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputHidden value="true">
        <f:validator validatorId="xorValidator" />
        <f:attribute name="input1" value="form:input1" />
        <f:attribute name="input2" value="form:input2" />
    </h:inputHidden>
    <h:inputText id="input1" value="#{bean.input1}" required="#{empty param['form:input2']}" />
    <h:inputText id="input2" value="#{bean.input2}" required="#{empty param['form:input1']}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

with

```
@FacesValidator(value="xorValidator")
public class XorValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        UIInput input1 = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent((String) component.getAttributes().get("input1"));
        UIInput input2 = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent((String) component.getAttributes().get("input2"));

        Object value1 = input1.getSubmittedValue();
        Object value2 = input2.getSubmittedValue();

        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I will try this and report if it works for me. It sounds like the old question: "Is this a bug or a feature?" ;-)

Comment: @BalusC sorry bothering you, im trying to do the same by using the bean validation in jsf 2.0 here is the link to the question i have posted on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621337/cross-field-custom-constraint-annotation-not-working   i'll be greatfull if you take a look at this ... regards

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the {feature|bug} with the getValue() / getSubmittedValue() - methods in 2.x you could try the RequiredIf-Annotation for XOR validation:

`@RequiredIf(validationErrorMsgKey = "requiredField", valueOf = { "pvol" } , is = RequiredIfType.empty )`
private String bbvol;

`@RequiredIf(validationErrorMsgKey = "requiredField", valueOf = { "bbvol" } , is = RequiredIfType.empty )`
private String pvol;

That works for me like a charm in a similiar validation constellation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interesting approach. Never heard of this annotation. Google says this is a MyFaces extension, right?

Comment: Yes, its included in myfaces-extval-property-validation-2.x.jar. Unfortunately there is nearly no documentation on its usage. (at least I could not find any ...). You'll also need myfaces-extval-core.jar. (and maybe even persistence-api.jar).