# Model value of first input component is null in validator of second component

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to get the value of a `<p: selectOneMenu />` for use in a validator via `<f:attribute>`:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="tDocument" value="#{usuarioController.persona.tipoDocumento}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.selectOne}" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{tipeListController.tipoIdentificacion}" var="_tDocument" itemValue="#{_tDocument}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputText id="doc" value="#{usuarioController.persona.num_documento}" required="true" validator="ciRucValidator">
    <f:attribute id="idenType" name="identificationType" value="#{usuarioController.persona.tipoDocumento}" />
</p:inputText>
```

But when trying to get it in the validator as below I get `null`:

```
TipoIdentificacion identificationType = (TipoIdentificacion) component.getAttributes().get("identificationType");
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: try component.getAttributes().get("idenType") instead of component.getAttributes().get("identificationType"), using the id of the attribute

Comment: I tried to use the component id instead of the attribute name, but I still get the same error.

Comment: are these wrapped by a form element ?

Comment: The f:attribute doesn't support `id` attribute anyway. And, if it wasn't in a form, the validator wouldn't be hit in first place.

Comment: thanks you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model value is set during 4th phase "Update Model Values". However, validators run during 3rd phase "Process Validators". That is thus one phase earlier. It should be obvious that the updated model value of the other component is not available at that moment.

The canonical approach is to just pass the component and then extract the value directly from it via `UIInput#getValue()` or `UIInput#getSubmittedValue()` depending on the order of the components.

```
<p:selectOneMenu binding="#{tDocument}" ...>
    ...
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:inputText ... validator="ciRucValidator">
    <f:attribute name="tDocument" value="#{tDocument}" />
</p:inputText>
```

Note that I removed `<f:attribute id>`, [this doesn't exist](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/attribute.html), and also note that `binding` example is as-is; [very importantingly **without** a bean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used).

You can grab it in the validator as below:

```
UIInput tDocument = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("tDocument");
TipoIdentificacion identificationType = (TipoIdentificacion) tDocument.getValue();
// ...
```

This also gives you the opportunity to invalidate the other component via `setValid(false)` if necessary.

#### See also:

- [How to get the value of another component in a custom validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608145/how-to-get-the-value-of-another-component-in-a-custom-validator)